# Why isn't the libc++'s implementation of the shared_ptr's templated move assignment operator noexcept

Tags: c++, c++11, llvm, clang++, libc++

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%3D), the shared_ptr's templated move assignment operator should be `noexcept`. [Libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/c2fc1702cb3a3d5cc9c40de47f63b4c8f3f1d09c/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr.h#L389-L395) implements it, but [libc++](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/5c40c994c329aa7e521c53cbc893426c90203941/libcxx/include/__memory/shared_ptr.h#L989-L1001) doesn't. Actually, both the `swap` member function and the move constructor are `noexcept`. Why?

```
template<class _Tp>
template<class _Yp>
inline
typename enable_if
<
    __compatible_with<_Yp, typename shared_ptr<_Tp>::element_type>::value,
    shared_ptr<_Tp>&
>::type
shared_ptr<_Tp>::operator=(shared_ptr<_Yp>&& __r) // <--- not noexcept
{
    shared_ptr(_VSTD::move(__r)).swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.